# Is there a way to clear stale/orphaned subprocesses from VS Code's "Debug Console" list?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Every time I debug a Python app in VS Code that includes multithreading/asyncio, I end up with orphaned subprocesses listed in the "Debug Console" dropdown which makes identifying the current active thread(s) nearly impossible. Is there a way to clear this list without closing the terminal, or some other way to stop this from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click that little hamburger icon on top right of the debug (next to filter text field) a bunch of times, it clears out faster than there are number of orphaned subprocesses.

Comment: I edited to turn this into an answer. If you are not sure it is one please delete the post.

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually clear them from the dropdown list, it only wipes the console output.